# Random Points with Polygon ID

Tags: qgis, point-in-polygon

In QGIS 3.4, I would like to place random points inside each polygon using a field from an attribute in the polygon layer and tag each point with its polygon id.  Currently, I use Random Points inside Polygon.  The output is what I am looking for exempt that the function doesn't carry over the polygon ID.  Therefore, I have to do a Spatial Join back with the Polygon layer.  This step is taking a long time due to performing an linear search.

Is there a way to drop random points and track the polygon ID back to the point?  A plugin?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Try to do it with the [Join attributes by Location](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#id47) tool.

Comment: Thanks!!  Join attributes by Location is the straight forward way.  It is going to take 4 days to complete on a i5 2.1GHz 32GB,

Comment: You are welcome! 4 days for a spatial join I don't think it's a reasonable time. In fact, I didn't quite understand what you meant by linear search. I believe that can be improved. Do both polygon a points layers have a spatial index already created? Later I will write a detailed answer.

Comment: I agree with @GabrielDeLuca, 4 days is a crazy long time for a spatial join. I work on a computer with an i5 core (not sure off the top of my head about its other specs) and it can be slow, but never that slow. There must be another issue going on, eg, if the point layer is a shapefile with many thousands of points you might be hitting the size limit of the shapefile format. Please add some details to your question: what file format, how many polygons, and how many points?

Comment: .shp  Polygons: 626; Points 1.6M.  Polygons have a filed on how many points to drop on each polygon.  I used random points in polygon to create a new layer with points.  I just want to index the points back to the polygon. The problem seems to be that I am using a previous layer to join that have many more polygons (1M) (which is what I intended to do anyway) .  By linear search I meant that the join is searching thorough the whole array (in the worst case) before finding the intersect match so it is a N^2 type search.  I guess that I have to wait for the Join to finish...  28% right now